# Get back project back after signed apk android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

How to get back the whole android project after generate signed apk android studio ? I have generated the apk and send to dropbox, when I get the project file and open it using Android Studio, my project looked like this

[image]

Is there a way I can import the whole project back ?? Thanks

Comment: update your android studio first

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I don't understand. After generate an apk,need to update ?

Comment: no. you got just old version 1.3 as seen on the screenshot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating a signed apk does not modify your project. Did you delete your project?

Comment: If you didn't delete your project, then you're looking in the wrong place. If you open up Android Studio, doesn't it just show the project in either the project explorer or recent projects or something?

Comment: after generate signed apk android studio I can't open back my project

Comment: When you open Android Studio it should open the last project that was open or (if you have more than 1) it should display a list of project for you to choose. In any case, you can always go to File -> Open Recent and choose your project there